# How can I make a car turn when I want to go the other way using arrows on the keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1iaz.jpg) 
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPYr.png)

On visual studio code I can move the car forth and back with the arrows  on the keyboard. but it doesnt turn when I want to go opposite ways. Is there a way to do with animation. also it doesnt wanna move on the code snippet for some reason but it works on my visual studio code

```js
var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
var boxEl = document.querySelector("div");


var left = 0;
var top = 180;

var speed = 10;

bodyEl.addEventListener ("keydown", moveBox);

function moveBox(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        left -= speed;
    }

    else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        left += speed;
    }

    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        top -= speed;
    }

    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        top += speed;
    }


    boxEl.style.top = top + "px";
    boxEl.style.left = left + "px";

}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1iaz.jpg");
    cursor: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dPYr.png" height="300px" width="300px" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a custom class while the right arrow press and remove it while the left arrow press. you can do the same for up and down arrow keys.

Add CSS -

```
div.reverse img {
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
 }
```

Update function JS -

```
function moveBox(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        boxEl.classList.remove("reverse");
        left -= speed;
    }

    else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        boxEl.classList.add("reverse");
        left += speed;
    }

    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        top -= speed;
    }

    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        top += speed;
    }


    boxEl.style.top = top + "px";
    boxEl.style.left = left + "px";

}
```